# Coupling ion ray with a EM wave and penetration depth

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, plasma-physics, microwaves

[Ion sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_source) are devices that allow creating ion beams (e.g. argon ions) and to project them outside the device, for example to be further processed by a particle accelerator, or to irradiate materials or biological tissues etc.

Now, suppose the ion beam is coupled with an EM wave, especially of microwave frequency.
For me, that means that the ions are in some sense "carried" by the wave and vibrate at the same frequency (this mental image may be somewhat inexact).
In these conditions, it is natural to suspect that at certain frequencies of the EM wave, depending upon the irradiated material, the penetration depth of the ion beam will be increased or decreased.

Is there something known about that? what work has been done in this domain? references?

Comment: RFQ cavities have the ions "surf" the rf. But the 'vibrate' with the wave is off...

Comment: @Jon Custer. Do you mean that the term "vibrate" is inadequate or something else?

Comment: The gyrofrequency of the ions must match that of the rf wave if you want them to do something called gyrosurfing, which is what I think you are trying to elude to...

Comment: Sorry, never heard about gyrosurfing.